# Given a finite set of points. How can I make a ball around this points, so that the intersection of any two balls are empty

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, algorithms

I'm looking for an algorithm or a theoretical result for the following problem:

Given the finite set of points $X = \{x_{1},\ldots,x_{d}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$. For $x \in X$ we define $B_{r}(x)$ as the ball around $x$ with radius $r \geq 0$, i.e.,
$$
B_{r}(x) := \{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid \lvert \rvert x -y\lvert \rvert_{2} \leq r\}.
$$

My question is, how can I efficiently compute all the radius, such that
$$
B_{r}(x) ~~\cap ~~ B_{r'}(x') = \emptyset \quad \text{for all } x,x' \in X. 
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple. Let $S=\{\|x-x'\|:x\neq x', x,x'\in X\}$. Then $S$ is a finite set of positive numbers. Since $S$ is finite, $\min(S)>0$. Take any number $\delta>0$ that satisfies $\delta<\frac{\min(S)}{2}$. Then the balls $\{B_\delta(x)\}_{x\in X}$ are pairwise disjoint for $x\in X$.

Let's verify this: If $y\in B_\delta(x)\cap B_\delta(x')$, then $\|x-y\|<\delta$ and $\|y-x'\|<\delta$. Thus $\|x-x'\|\leq\|x-y\|+\|y-x'\|<2\delta<\min(S) $, a contradiction.